# react, map component, unexpected result

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, components

I am building Weather App, my idea is to save city name in database/localhost, place cities in useState(right now it's hard coded), iterate using map in first child component and display in second child component.

The problem is that 2nd child component outputs only one element (event though console.log prints both)

BTW  when I change code in my editor and save, then another 'li' element appears

### main component

```
const App = () => {

    const [cities, setCities] = useState(['London', 'Berlin']);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <DisplayWeather displayWeather={cities}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

### first child component

```
const DisplayWeather = ({displayWeather}) => {


    const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState([]);

    const apiKey = '4c97ef52cb86a6fa1cff027ac4a37671';


    useEffect(() => {
    
        displayWeather.map(async city=>{
       
            const res =await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`)
            const data = await res.json();
             
                setFetchData([...fetchData , data]);
           
        })
        
    }, [])


    return (
        <>
            {fetchData.map(data=>(            
                 <ul>
                     <Weather                        
                        data={data}/> 
                  </ul>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default DisplayWeather
```

### second child component

```
const Weather = ({data}) => {


    console.log(data) // it prints correctly both data


    return (

        <li>       
            {data.name} //display only one data
        </li>
    )
}

export default Weather
```

Comment: What is the structure of your data?

Comment: Data it's object fetched from API

Comment: I know that! But, what is the structure when you do a `console.log(data)`

Comment: It's still that object

{coord: {…}, weather: Array(1), base: "stations", main: {…}, visibility: 10000, …}
base: "stations"
clouds: {all: 0}
cod: 200
coord: {lon: 19.565, lat: 50.2813}
dt: 1620762052
id: 3090146
main: {temp: 20.25, feels_like: 19.53, temp_min: 18.89, temp_max: 22, pressure: 1008, …}
name: "Olkusz"
sys: {type: 1, id: 1701, country: "PL", sunrise: 1620702034, sunset: 1620756945}
timezone: 7200
visibility: 10000
weather: [{…}]
wind: {speed: 4.12, deg: 80}
__proto__: Object

Comment: Is this the `console.log()` within the `Wether` component

Comment: Or you get a couple of those?

Comment: yes in Weather component

Comment: You only have one weather data then? So how is the other one supposed to be there?

Comment: I use map, weather components are as many as cities( from useState in parent component)

Comment: Makes sense! See my update answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Problem

The `setFetchData` hooks setter method is asynchronous by default, it doesn't give you the updated value of the state immediately after it is set.

When the `weather` result for the second `city` is returned and set to state, the current value `fetchData` at the time is still an empty array, so you're essentially spreading an empty array with the second `weather` result

#### Solution

Pass a callback to your `setFetchData` and get the current previous value of the `state` and then continue with your spread accordingly.

Like this

```js
setFetchData((previousData) => [...previousData, data]);
```

Comment: Thanks man, this solution works.

But I am still confused why it didn't worked because I understand that useState is asynchronous but looking at react dev tools, state and props were correct, so even if this comes later(asynchronous), I thought change in state or props should render the site and eventually display that

Comment: Think of it like each of the `.map()` callback function is pushed into the call stack with a `fetchData` of an empty array, and when they're executed they don't get the state update